# Using the org.apache.commons configurations

Tags: java

I am just trying to load a config file with apache configurations.
I dont know why it is failing? The URL path looks to be ok check the red marking in the picture.

[image]

Thanks
Maestro

Comment: You see you have an error there: No classfound: org.apache...Log

Comment: the exception is noClassDefFound the library is not complete what is the version and what is the jar file

Comment: Hi do you mean the java version? I am using java 1.8. The apache library from the release notes say RELEASE-NOTES.txt 1811478 2017-10-08 11:52:32Z oheger $
                        Apache Commons Configuration
                               Version 2.2
                               Release Notes

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should have understood that i did not have the complete apache library that was needed. No i added the apache lang, logging , beanutils and it is working fine. Thansk